# Image preview missing in Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Chrome Developer tools stopped displaying preview of CSS background images.
It used to display it like this (this is taken from a different machine):

[image]

But now it's just showing this:

[image]

The tooltip is working fine for images placed in HTML (as opposed to CSS).

Anyone knows how to bring it back? This image preview and especially the size of the image was super useful. Restoring defaults didn't help.

Checked on Chrome Version 36.0.1985.18 dev

Comment: You got me thinking, so I installed a last stable version (35.0.1916.114) and the problem is gone. It's been like that for at least a few weeks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is most likely due to the fact you are using a developer version of Chrome, which is probably not stable.

Try moving back to a stable release to see if this fixes the issue (it should). If it does, you will need to consider the trade off between the new features of the release and the bugs it has.

I would GUESS this is a bug and will be fixed by the time it is released

Comment: I'm having this issue as well and in this instance I am not running a developer version where the issue is occurring.